# error when using "vagrant box add laravel/homestead" on OSX

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am trying to add the laravel/homestead box to my vagrant installation and keep getting the error "The program 'vagrant' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install vagrant"

I have virtual box installed and working (I use it regularly) and I just downloaded vagrant and it DID say it downloaded successfully. Some forums suggest my installation is not up to date but I installed it about 15 minutes ago so I don't think that could be the case.

Also, I have already created a new directory using mkdir, then used "vagrant init hashicorp/precise32" and then "vagrant ssh" which have all been successful. The next thing I try to do is add the box and it won't work. I have never used vagrant before so I am unfamiliar with this. Any help is appreciated!

PS I'm on OSX El Capitan

Comment: Did you `download` it or `installed` it with `sudo apt-get install vagrant`?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin OP is on an OSX host so there is no apt-get

Comment: OP: You seem to be providing conflicting information. If your host is OSX, the error message `The program 'vagrant' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install vagrant` doesn't make any sense - that error would come from a linux box. What happens if you run `lsb_release -a` or `system_profiler`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful after so many months, but I ran into this same problem yesterday. There appears to be a lot of information about this in the vagrant git forums.

As a workaround (not fix) I downgraded to virtualBox 5.0, and vagrant 1.7.4